# Google Transcoder API fails if the video duration is less then 5s

Tags: google-cloud-transcoder

I'm not sure how long the issue has been happening, it must have been a few months. In first it definitely works for short videos (less then 5s). Now it fails. Is there a way to solve it?

```
  "code": 3,
  "message": "Request field config.editList is invalid duration, expected edit list duration should be atleast 5s long, current duration is 2.554195s.",
  "details": [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
      "fieldViolations": [
        {
          "field": "config.editList",
          "description": "InvalidInputDuration"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It says right there in the error that it must be at least 5 seconds long...

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas It seems that they changed limitations so it affects our product. On the other hand there is no documentation about the limitation. Maybe someone suggest a solution or a workaround about configuration...

Comment: Increase video length to 5 sec? This is one of the risks you take when using 3rd party components and libraries.

Comment: Don't trust any of the Google services, they are terrible. I would just run FFMPEG on the server with a background server task (Cloud run jobs)